# Edit price template in view order Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, price

Prices in store are inclusive of tax.  But I am trying to separate Tax out of the price in the client dashboard.  In view order the file

```
vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml
```

generates the code for the item order breakdown :

```
<?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection(); ?>
<?php $_index = 0; ?>
<?php $_count = $_items->count(); ?>
<?php $_giftMessage = ''?>
<?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
<?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
continue;
} ?>         <tbody>
            <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
```

Calling the price information from elsewhere.  Is there a way to edit the `$block->getItemHtml($_item)` & be able to change the price output but just for this page?  Or create a new block with edited price information, so it will not affect other calls of the same block?

Answer (score 0):

If you go through comments posted by experts you will find that experts do not recommend price to be entered inclusive of taxes as they will result in issues.
Suggested option is if needed change your price code block to handle price displays rather then using this configuration option of product price inclusive of taxes.
I have handled some tax related exemption cases and there I found that in few places it can be really a trouble thing.

Comment: where are the comments to see the issues?  Most countries outside the USA include taxes in the price.  There is just one screen where I want to separate out the taxes